# Slow triple inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following query (names were altered) and it is really slow. I don't know if it is that slow because it could be written better or because I am lacking indexes. Also, how should I create indexes, as most of the joins are on imaginary tables?

```
select y.radish, g.enton
from great g 
inner join(
    select sr.radish, sr.greatReferenceID
    from spaceRadish sr
    inner join(
        select s.id
        from super s
        inner join experiments e
        on s.CID = e.analysis) x
    on sr.springID = x.id) y
on g.id = y.greatReferenceID
```

Output from explain select:

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', '<derived2>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '14085960', ''
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'g', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'y.greatReferenceID', '1', ''
'2', 'DERIVED', '<derived3>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '287', ''
'2', 'DERIVED', 'sr', 'ref', 'springID', 'springID', '4', 'x.id', '831666', ''
'3', 'DERIVED', 'e', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '3271', ''
'3', 'DERIVED', 's', 'ref', 'CID,CID_2', 'CID', '767', 'cpp.e.analysis', '16', 'Using where; Using index'
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the all fields you are using in join and where conditions? How big are your tables?

Comment: show us: sample data, expected results, tables description and the explain on the query

Comment: btw what do you mean with _imaginary tables?_ temporary tables maybe?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski I have one really big table with 14969400 rows, the others are a few  thousand to a few hundred thousand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try avoid subbquery

```
    select y.radish, g.enton
    from great g 
    inner join spaceRadish sr ON  sr.greatReferenceID = g.id
    inner join super s  s.id = sr.springID
    inner join experiments e on s.CID = e.analysis
```

and be sure you have proper index on

```
    table  great  composite index on (id, enton)
    table spaceRadish composite index on (greatReferenceID, springID)
    table super cmposite index on (id, cid)
    table experiments index  on analysis
```

Comment: I had to substitute y.radish by sr.radish in your query as y was only the name for the temporary table. It was really quick, but didn't provide the right outcome, as there were duplicated instances of g.enton, which was not the case in the original query

Comment: EDIT: Never mind, it was because of the ordering. Thank you, with the restructuring, it was much quicker